# What happens when you poop on a human as the Peyote Bird (aerial attack)?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In GTA V, you can turn into a bird when eating the [air peyote](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Peyote_Plants). Check this video:

When the player's in bird form, he can fly & poop. The game call it "aerial attack", but Trevor use the word 'shit', so the word's kind of stick to my mind. Beside, I don't want people to misunderstand that I'm talking about aerial attack from a plane.

I've never successfully pooped on human when in bird form, I wonder what when we successfully land the bird's shit on human, will the human react?

Comment: why down vote? I think this is a legit question.